# Mongodb with Python's "set()" type

Tags: python, mongodb

I am building a web App with mongoDB as the backend.  Some of the documents need to store a collection of items in some sort of list, and then the system will need to frequently check if a specified item is present in that list.  Using Python's 'in' operator takes Big-O(N) time, n being the size of the list.  Since these list can get quite large, I want something faster than that.  Python's 'set' type does this operation in constant time (and enforces uniqueness, which is good in my case), but is considered an invalid data type to put in MongoDB.

So what's the best way to do this?  Is there some way to just use a regular list and exploit mongo's indexing features?  Again, I want to know, for a given document in a collection, does a list inside that document contain particular element?

Comment: Note that Big-O(n) time *is* linear time, and `set` works in Big-O(1) time in the average case which is *constant* time. However, `set` is still Big-O(n) time in the worst-case (it can be Big-O(log n) worst-case time too, but I think Python's is O(n)...)

Comment: Worst case is only when you have 100% collisions. It's implemented as an Hastable, it's O(1) as much as dictionaries.

Comment: @cha0site sorry I meant to write *constant* time, not *linear*.  I corrected it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can represent a set using a dictionary. Your elements become the keys, and all the values can be set to a constant such as 1. The in operator checks for the existence of a key.

EDIT. MongoDB stores a dict as a BSON document, where the keys must be strings (with some additional restrictions), so the above advice is of limited use.

Comment: Oh that's genius!  Why is that allowed but a 'set' type is not allowed?  I thought it had something to do with the ability or inability of a data type to be hashed, but then it wouldn't make sense that dictionaries are allowed.  I actually think I figured out how to get mongo to index the elements of the inner list of elements, so I can do logarithmic time queries of "find item of some id that has some element in its list" and I can check if the query returns with a cursor or null.  But thanks for the hint, I might use it later.